# User32 GetWindowTextA with UTF-8 in Java?

Tags: java, character-encoding

The following is intended to try to get the active window's title and stores to `title`.

```java
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
User32.instance.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, buffer, buffer.length);
String title = Native.toString(buffer);
```

In `title` it is supposed to be stored something similar to `"猫の動画 - YouTube - Google Chrome"`; since let's say I was opening a YouTube tab on the Chrome browser, where its title has non-alphabetical characters but UTF-8 compatible.

However, on contrary to my expectation, `title` actually has something similar to `"??????? - YouTube - Google Chrome"`.

I also tried some variants such as the following; But they didn't solve the garbled character issue.

```java
String title = new String( buffer, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
```

How can I solve the issue? Thanks.

### additional information

The following is the entire Java script:

```java
package Main;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class windowcapture {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException {
        int hWnd = User32.instance.GetForegroundWindow();
        WindowInfo window = getWindowInfo(hWnd);
    }

    public static WindowInfo getWindowInfo(int hWnd) {
        RECT r = new RECT();
        User32.instance.GetWindowRect(hWnd, r);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        User32.instance.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, buffer, buffer.length);
        String title = Native.toString(buffer);
        WindowInfo info = new WindowInfo(hWnd, r, title);
        return info;
    }

    public static interface WndEnumProc extends StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback {
        boolean callback(int hWnd, int lParam);
    }

    public static interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        public static final String SHELL_TRAY_WND = "Shell_TrayWnd";
        public static final int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
        public static final int MIN_ALL = 0x1a3;
        public static final int MIN_ALL_UNDO = 0x1a0;

        final User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

        boolean EnumWindows(WndEnumProc wndenumproc, int lParam);

        boolean IsWindowVisible(int hWnd);

        int GetWindowRect(int hWnd, RECT r);

        void GetWindowTextA(int hWnd, byte[] buffer, int buflen);

        int GetTopWindow(int hWnd);

        int GetWindow(int hWnd, int flag);

        boolean ShowWindow(int hWnd);

        boolean BringWindowToTop(int hWnd);

        int GetActiveWindow();

        boolean SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);
        
        // HWND GetForegroundWindow();
        int GetForegroundWindow();

        int FindWindowA(String winClass, String title);

        long SendMessageA(int hWnd, int msg, int num1, int num2);

        final int GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;
    }

    public static class RECT extends Structure {
        public int left, top, right, bottom;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            List<String> order = new ArrayList<>();
            order.add("left");
            order.add("top");
            order.add("right");
            order.add("bottom");
            return order;
        }
    }

    public static class WindowInfo {
        int hwnd;
        RECT rect;
        String title;

        public WindowInfo(int hwnd, RECT rect, String title) {
            this.hwnd = hwnd;
            this.rect = rect;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("(%d,%d)-(%d,%d) : \"%s\"", rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, title);
        }
    }
}
```

### the latest (current) version

```java
package Main;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class windowcapture {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException {
        int hWnd = User32.instance.GetForegroundWindow();
        WindowInfo window = getWindowInfo(hWnd);
    }

    public static WindowInfo getWindowInfo(int hWnd) {
        RECT r = new RECT();
        User32.instance.GetWindowRect(hWnd, r);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        // User32.instance.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, buffer, buffer.length);
        User32.instance.GetWindowTextW(hWnd, buffer, buffer.length);

        // FileOutputStream fos = null;
        // try {
        //     fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("./out/hoge.txt"), true);
        //     fos.write(buffer);
        //     fos.flush();
        //     System.out.println("File Written Successfully");
        // } catch (IOException ioe) {
        //     ioe.printStackTrace();
        // } finally {
        //     try {
        //         if (fos != null) {
        //             fos.close();
        //         }
        //     } catch (IOException ioe) {
        //         System.out.println("Error in closing the Stream");
        //     }
        // }

        String title = Native.toString(buffer);
        // String title = new String( buffer, Charset.forName("x-MS950-HKSCS") );
        // String title = new String( buffer, Charset.forName("UTF_16BE") );
        // String title = new String( buffer, Charset.forName("UTF-8") );
        // String title = Native.toString(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE);
        WindowInfo info = new WindowInfo(hWnd, r, title);
        return info;
    }

    public static interface WndEnumProc extends StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback {
        boolean callback(int hWnd, int lParam);
    }

    public static interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        public static final String SHELL_TRAY_WND = "Shell_TrayWnd";
        public static final int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
        public static final int MIN_ALL = 0x1a3;
        public static final int MIN_ALL_UNDO = 0x1a0;

        final User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

        boolean EnumWindows(WndEnumProc wndenumproc, int lParam);

        boolean IsWindowVisible(int hWnd);

        int GetWindowRect(int hWnd, RECT r);

        void GetWindowTextA(int hWnd, byte[] buffer, int buflen);
        void GetWindowTextW(int hWnd, byte[] buffer, int buflen);

        int GetTopWindow(int hWnd);

        int GetWindow(int hWnd, int flag);

        boolean ShowWindow(int hWnd);

        boolean BringWindowToTop(int hWnd);

        int GetActiveWindow();

        boolean SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);
        
        // HWND GetForegroundWindow();
        int GetForegroundWindow();

        int FindWindowA(String winClass, String title);

        long SendMessageA(int hWnd, int msg, int num1, int num2);

        final int GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;
    }

    public static class RECT extends Structure {
        public int left, top, right, bottom;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            List<String> order = new ArrayList<>();
            order.add("left");
            order.add("top");
            order.add("right");
            order.add("bottom");
            return order;
        }
    }

    public static class WindowInfo {
        int hwnd;
        RECT rect;
        String title;

        public WindowInfo(int hwnd, RECT rect, String title) {
            this.hwnd = hwnd;
            this.rect = rect;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("(%d,%d)-(%d,%d) : \"%s\"", rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What library is that? Also, `GetWindowTextW` might be more appropriate.

Comment: Before `Native.toString` it would maybe be instructive to dump `buffer` to file with a `FileOutputStream`. Would be interesting to see the results

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I could say the library is "user32", I think? I think it's called through "StdCallLibrary" thing. I just added the additional information section to the entire script, please take a look there.

Comment: In addition to what @JohannesKuhn said, Windows is not known for its Unicode prowess, so something like `String title = new String( buffer, Charset.forName("x-MS950-HKSCS");` might be more likely

Comment: @g00se depends on the encoding that specific windows instance uses. The *W functions use unicode, which makes things a bit easier...

Comment: I tried the `FileOutputStream` way to see if the output in the file, it's still garbled, but not `?????`, but it says `nullnullnull`. Also tried the `Charset.forName("x-MS950-HKSCS")` way, but it didn't trick, it still shows `?????` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "A" in `GetWindowTextA` stands for ANSI, no? ANSI doesn't have those characters, hence trivially `GetWindowTextA` cannot possibly give you what you want here, and thus no amount of java code is going to fix this.

You want `GetWindowTextW`. I think that might return UTF16LE, you may have to play around a bit with trying different encodings, but at least the data you get back from windows still has what you want (vs `A` which has already deleted the chinese characters, given that ANSI does not support them).

Comment: I changed `void GetWindowTextA(int hWnd, byte[] buffer, int buflen);` to `void GetWindowTextW(int hWnd, byte[] buffer, int buflen);`, and `User32.instance.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, buffer, buffer.length);` to `User32.instance.GetWindowTextW(hWnd, buffer, buffer.length);` respectively, but now I started to store to `title` the first one character; For example, while it's supposed to be `my great video - YouTube - Google` it is `m`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you edit your code to show your latest? I think I can guess what's happening. `Native.toString` is seeing the first null byte as the termination of the string. IOW it doesn't support UTF-16

Comment: ("my" == 0x00, 0x6d, 0x00, 0x79) in UTF-16

Comment: @Lime - yes, as I said, you need to play around with encodings. It's "working", in the sense that you're now getting bytes back that can be turned into the chinese characters. But not with Native.toString. Perhaps `Native.toString(byteBuf, StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE)`. Print the content of that byte array, play around with it.

Comment: @g00se I have just added the latest version

Comment: I believe Windows wide chars are in **UTF16-LE**, as little endian is for the X86 family of processors.

Comment: @JoopEggen wow, `new String( buffer, Charset.forName("UTF_16LE") );` worked like a charm. thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I typed UTF16BE in my answer, which is obviously entirely wrong. My brain was telling me to pick an endianness because windows does the weird one, and promptly I typed the wrong endianness! I edited the answer, my apologies, and glad to hear all is working as want, Lime :) - thanks @JoopEggen for the correction.